# Insert into com select

Tags: sql

Preciso fazer uma inserção do tipo

```
INSERT INTO your_table SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

mas, preciso que o id, e a segunda coluna que é uma id_fk eu possa setar.

Preciso fazer uma transferência da tupla para outro usuário, copiando todas as informações mas, passando novos  id, id_fk e nome

algum macete?

Comment: Explique melhor, sua pergunta não está clara

Comment: Seria interessante adicionar a estrutura das tabelas envolvidas.

Comment: Se possível colocar algum exemplo, pois não ficou muito claro a dúvida

Answer (score 1):

tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (nome_campo1,nome_campo2) VALUES (select nome_campo1,nome_campo2 from tabela)
```

Observação: Apenas substitua o 'nome_campo' pelos campos em questão, lembrando que tanto após o 'INSERT INTO' e o 'SELECT', a ordem dos campos devem ser a mesma.
Observação 2: Como vc não especificou em qual database vc esta fazendo esse SQL (Mysql, Postgree, SQlServer), eu usei a sintaxe do PostgreSQL, talvez vc precise adaptar o código para o banco q vc está usando

Answer (score 0):

basta você alterar o select, e não usar *

```
INSERT INTO your_table 
              SELECT 
                 '1' as novo_id, 
                 '2' as nova_fk, 
                 t.outros_campos 
              FROM temp_table t;
```